# Disable text selection in Web browser control

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

How can I disable text selection in Web browser control in Visual Basic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can. You could render a transparent control over the WebBrowser control. But that would not only prevent text from being select, but pretty much prevent any interaction with the page altogether.

Comment: are you sure that there's no other way ?

Comment: i did disable drop down function, but he can just select text down to see what i have down in the website